# Eclipse projects vs build path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, buildpath

I am building a library which wraps some code around spymemcached client. This is called CacheClient. This is s simple Java project. I put the spymemcached.jar into its lib folder.

Here is how it looks like, also you can see the build path settings:

> **Library: CacheClient Project: cacheclient.jar**
>
> - lib
>
>   - spymemcached.jar
>
> Java Build Path / Libraries Tab:
>   spymemcached.jar - CacheClient/lib/spymemcached.jar

What I am doing is I am building a simple java web project which is using this library.

> **WebApp: ServiceWebApp Project: servicewebapp.war**
>
> - WebContent
>
>   - WEB-INF
>
>     - lib
>
>       - EMPTY
>
> Java Build Path / Projects Tab: CacheClient

So, my Webapp's build path is set to using the CacheClient project. I copied the cacheclient.jar into tomcat's lib directory and deployed the ServiceWebApp.

When I run the web app, it fails as it says my CacheClient code is looking for the spymemcached classes (ClassNotFoundException).

I could solve this by putting spymemcached.jar into tomcat's lib directory but it would be great if there will be an other solution.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of making the lib available in your web app would be to put the lib's jar to your WEB-INF/lib directory.

If you don't want to do it manually, check this link about how this can be automated: [Adding 3rd party jars to WEB-INF/lib automatically using Eclipse/Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467038/adding-3rd-party-jars-to-web-inf-lib-automatically-using-eclipse-tomcat)

Comment: OK this was the solution. I put the cacheclient.jar and also the spymemcached.jar into the web app's WEB-INF/lib dir. However the spymemcached.jar is also in the cacheclient.jar's lib dir. As I can see to reference a class from a jar inside a library is not natively supported, so One-Jar or any other packaging is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case cacheclient.jar has a dependency on spymemcached.jar. But when your cacheclient.jar is built it's not packaged with spymemcached.jar. So just copying cacheclient.jar in tomcat/lib folder is not enough. In first place it's not a good practice to copy jar files in tomcat lib folder.

What you can do is copy both your jars in 
servicewebapp.war > WenContent>WEB-INF>lib that should work.