# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.Struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Tags: java, maven, struts2, classnotfoundexception

I have built a very simple application using Struts 2, I have searched a lot and tried everything but can not get away from this exception :

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.Struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom.xml file is :

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"


        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Struts2tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>Struts2tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/struts/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2tutorial</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.Struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I get this exception when I compile it on tomcat,am using tomcat 7,please help.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759956/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts2-dispatcher-ng-filter-struts

Comment: @pmverma it has no correct answer please check before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Your version `struts2-core` is recent version which contains `org.apache.Struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`. It seems you have problem with the build process. How are you compiling, using maven?

Comment: @pmverma no am not using maven to build, am directly running it on tomcat server.

Comment: that's why. try `mvn clean install` from project root directory. A war file will be created under `target` folder.You can use this file to run in tomcat.

Comment: same error even after using this command in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your class define in web.xml is wrong. its org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.ng.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter not 
org.apache.Struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: no the path is fine, as I have extracted the jar file and saw the class inside, the path is correct.

Comment: as mentioned please change `org.apache.Struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` to `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` small `s` not capts, in web.xml the stacktrace also shows that at least it is one the problems