# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jena, semantic-web

I am getting this error while calling a java class in servlet.

Here is the error.

```
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QueryFactory
    com.complexible.common.csv.MuseumData.gts(MuseumData.java:109)
    com.complexible.common.csv.MuseumData.ass(MuseumData.java:89)
    com.complexible.common.csv.MuseumRDF.doGet(MuseumRDF.java:48)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    com.complexible.common.csv.MuseumData.gts(MuseumData.java:109)
    com.complexible.common.csv.MuseumData.ass(MuseumData.java:89)
    com.complexible.common.csv.MuseumRDF.doGet(MuseumRDF.java:48)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 logs.
```

Here is a code of my java class which will get the record from a RDF file using SPARQL and will return the output in JSON format in the console, then after i would catch the output and convert it into the string hence i could use that string into the servlet.

```
package com.complexible.common.csv;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class MuseumData {
     public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {


         String output=getrec();
         System.out.println(output);
         }


     public static String getrec() throws IOException 
        {
         String spr="prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"+ 
                 "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"+
                    "prefix crm:  <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/>\n"+        
                    "prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\n"+
                     "prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\n"+
                     "prefix crm: <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/rdfs/cidoc_crm_v5.0.4_official_release.rdfs#>\n"+       
                 "\n"+
                     //?title ?person ?type instead of *
                 "SELECT  * WHERE   { <http://phdprototype.tk/collectionimage/4D0BFF17-5810-4644-A550-D35EE090D4A8.png>"+
                     "crm:P3_has_note ?title ; "+
                 "crm:E21_Person ?person ;"+
                     "crm:E62_String ?type ;"+
                 "crm:P82_at_some_time_within ?year;"+
                     "crm:P33_used_specific_technique ?material;}";

          Query query = QueryFactory.create(spr);

         Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

         File f = new File("J:/Museum/data.rdf");
         model.read(new FileInputStream(f), "RDF/XML");

         //model.write(System.out, "TTL");

         final QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
         //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, exec.execSelect(), query);


         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
            // IMPORTANT: Save the old System.out!
            PrintStream old = System.out;
            // Tell Java to use your special stream
            System.setOut(ps);
            // Print some output: goes to your special stream
            ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(System.out, exec.execSelect());
            // Put things back
            System.out.flush();
            System.setOut(old);
            // Show what happened

           // return baos.toString();

            String gcr=baos.toString();
               return gcr;

        }

}
```

Here is a servlet code which will display the output in a browser.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    String rec=MuseumData.getrec();
    out.print(rec);


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the .jar for com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QueryFactory and put it in WEB-INF lib in your .war file.

Here's how to do it if you happened to be developing your servlets in the Eclipse IDE:

- [Adding 3rd party jars to WEB-INF/lib automatically using Eclipse/Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467038/adding-3rd-party-jars-to-web-inf-lib-automatically-using-eclipse-tomcat)

Comment: i added arq-2.8.7.jar but my problem is not resloved.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `jar` file containing the class `com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory` in your classpath. Please add it in your package / classpath

Comment: i add arq jar but my problem is not resloved

Answer (score 1):

Issue has beem resolved after added odbc6.jar in tomcat home lib and web-inf lib.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

As I was getting the same servlet exception error.. While upgrading from tomcat 6 to 8 .

Issue has beem resolved after added odbc6.jar in tomcat home lib and web-inf lib.