# Unable to compile class for JSP, import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, jsp

I'll post my first question on this forum so be kindly =)

My problem is that my import on my jsp file cannot be resolved :

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.javapapers.java.social.facebook.FBConnection" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
FBConnection fbConnection = new FBConnection();
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Java Facebook Login</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
<div
    style="margin: 0 auto; background-image: url(./img/fbloginbckgrnd.jpg); height: 360px; width: 610px;">
    <a href="<%=fbConnection.getFBAuthUrl()%>"><img
        style="margin-top: 138px;" src="./img/facebookloginbutton.png" />
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I crawled this forum since a day and I've done all what is said and I didn't found the solution for my problem...

here is the error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Matthieu\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Facebook_Login\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The import com.javapapers.java.social.facebook.FBConnection cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
FBConnection cannot be resolved to a type
3: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
4:  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
5: <%
6:  FBConnection fbConnection = new FBConnection();
7: %>
8: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
9: <html>


An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
FBConnection cannot be resolved to a type
3: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
4:  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
5: <%
6:  FBConnection fbConnection = new FBConnection();
7: %>
8: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
9: <html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
             org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I've put my classes on WEB-INF/classes as recommended (respecting the package name : com/javapapers/java/social/facebook)

I'm working on Eclipse Luna with a TomCat 8.0 server

Deployement assembly : 
[Deployement Assembly](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=630313DeployelentAssembly.png)

Librairies : 
[Librairies](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=184915librairies.png)

Sources : 
Test/src

But the error's still there

Can you help me please

Thanks

Comment: Its working for me, can you just check to your war by unzipping it whether it contains all classes in respective file or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, be sure the `.jar` file is in your classpath.

Second option is that your deployment does not correspond to what you want.

Check your Eclipse configuration for the Deployment Assembly:

- right click on your project
- select Deployment Assembly

If you're working on an external deployment (as opposed to workspace resources), check the resources at the deployment.

Comment: My jar is on my tomcat server classpath.
My Deployement Assembly looks like : 
Source : /src                                                    
Deploy Path : WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Your jar ? Isn't it a web project ?

Comment: It is, but there is a jar for specific functions and variables about Facebook(called restfb)

Comment: Ok, so you find this jar in the WEB-INF/lib of your project in your tomcat server deploiement classpath ?

Comment: In my lib there is a jar called Java-json.jar and in my classpath there is two jars called Bootstrap.jar and Tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: Just to be sure, the lib you're talking is in the WEB-INF/lib of your project deployed on the tomcat server, right ?
What is the name of the third-party jar containing the facebook classes ?

Comment: The lib in the WEB-INF of my project isn't in my tomcat's classpath.
Did I need to jar the 3 classes : FBConnection.java, FBGraph.java and MainMenu.java ? 
There is a jar downloaded from restfb.com who allows me to use the API ( the jar is on my PROJECT BUILD PATH)

Comment: Could you upload to your question a screenshot of your configuration in: JavaBuildPath>Librairies & source and of Deployment Assembly

Comment: Done, sorry I can't add Three links neither images (don't have 10 of reputation )

Comment: Try to create a folder in your WEB-INF called lib and put the jar in it. Also remove the line with the fb jar on both of your configuration. Then, try to redeploy,

Comment: In your librairies, you can see Web App Librairies, it actually corresponds to your WEB-INF/lib. You can open it to see what you have in it. Anyway, The problem you have here is clearly a configuration problem, I'd advice you to check some tutorials on Eclipse deploiement and project configuration. There is many misconfiguration in the different screenshots

Comment: Think it's a good solution, thanks sir for the time you give to my questions

Comment: You're welcome, think to come here to give the answer when you find it, or to close the topic. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You have to create following class in your src with same package name.

FBConnection.java
FBGraph.java
MainMenu.java

or you can download from the [link](http://javapapers.com/java/java-facebook-login-with-oauth-authentication/) and place in to your classpath once its compiled.
Make sure you have change FB_APP_ID,FB_APP_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI values accordingly in your FBConnection class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that FBConnection comes from a standard JAR file, then you need to ensure that the JAR file is on the JSP compiler's classpath when your JSP is compiled.

If you are deploying via a WAR file, then the library JAR needs to be in the WAR file.  If you are deploying using Eclipse's Tomcat integration, then the JAR needs to be a dependency of your Eclipse project.

For more information on how to do this: [Adding 3rd party jars to WEB-INF/lib automatically using Eclipse/Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467038/adding-3rd-party-jars-to-web-inf-lib-automatically-using-eclipse-tomcat)

Comment: The Jar is on my project BuildPath.

My lib is on the WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score -1):

You need to use correct App Id and App secret key. Refer the project here http://javapapers.com/java/java-facebook-login-with-oauth-authentication/ , import and change the FB_APP_ID and FB_APP_SECRET in FBConnection() class. Works for me.

Comment: Wrong configuration does not result in compilation time errors, but runtime error.